# Assign byte, UInt16 and UInt32 data types to Object data type in C#

Tags: c#

According to [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx) link, an Object data type can point to any data type. However, I get an error while doing so. My code is given below.

```
public bool Write(Object[] data, UInt32 numData)
{
   // Code
}
```

The code to test the Write API is below:

```
byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[256];
Random rnd = new Random();
UInt32 size = 256;
rnd.NextBytes(writeBuffer);
data.Write(writeBuffer, size);
```

Here, writeBuffer is a byte array, but it can also be a UInt16 or UInt32 array. I get an error in the **data.Write** line that there are **invalid arguments**.

Please let me know what the issue is.

EDIT 1:
My app provides a "write" API that can take a byte, UInt16 or UInt32 type array. Depending on the data type (which is set when the object is created), the API internally converts UInt16 and UInt32 to a byte array and passes it to the underneath layers. BTW, this is .Net Microframework, where the layers below the API are native c++ code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing "points" to anything there, no pointers involved, most (not all) types inherit from object, but that doesn't mean an array of something inherits from an array of object, it just means the elements in an array of object can be anything.

.Write expects an array of object and you're passing in an array of bytes, it won't work. You'd have to set the elements 1 by 1 (as a single byte is an object, so it can be stored in an object[])

However while i'm answering the question the question itself probably hides some bad design, why would you want to do that? Could you show us your functional use case so that we can suggest alternatives? Most often if you're working with objects or collection of objects directly, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: This is the design. My app provides a "write" API that can take a byte, UInt16 or UInt32 type array. Depending on the data type (which is set when the object is created), the API internally converts UInt16 and UInt32 to a byte array and passes it to the underneath layers. BTW, this is .Net Microframework, where the layers below the API are native c++ code. I am sorry for missing this detail.

Comment: Why bother with `object[]`? As Roman said, it won't work. `Array` would work, but you'd have to check what type array it was, and then throw exceptions etc. If you only need the three options, consider creating three overloads of `Write` taking `byte[]`, `ushort[]` and `uint[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the byte[] to an object array, like:

```
writeBuffer.Select(c=>(object)c).ToArray()
```

Note, that this is called "boxing" and will incur a performance cost, keep using byte[] if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the *boxing* penalty by using a generic definition for Write like this:

```
public bool Write<T>(T[] data, UInt32 size) {
  // Code
}
```

and invoking it like this:

```
data.Write(writeBuffer, size);
```

In most circumstances, as above, the C# compiler will be able to automatically determine the correct type to infer for *T*, though you can always specify it during the call like this when necessary:

```
UInt32[] uint32Array;
// :
data.Write<UInt32>(uint32Array, (UInt32)uint32Array.Count());
```